# Unable to access jarfile in Windows 8.1

Tags: java, jar, windows-8.1

I have a problem trying to install mondrian. The installer is a .jar file. If I double clik it, a windows console opens, but it closes immediatly. If I try with the console and I write "java -jar mondrian", I get "Error: Unable to access jarfile mondrian".

I'm using Windows 8.1.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You need the full filename of the jar file you are trying to execute

```
java -jar mondrian.jar
```

Regardless, I think you should really be referring to the [Mondrian installation guide](http://mondrian.pentaho.com/documentation/installation.php), from which you'll see that the command you need to enter is different from what you are attempting to do.

Comment: Thanks, but If I try that way I get "no main manifest attribute, in mondrian.jar".

Comment: Which is a step in the right direction, because at least then the jar is being examined, whereas previously it could not be located.

Comment: @vjsp - see the link I added. I think you should be following the installation guide more closely.